# Using UniqueConstraint to solve "get() returned more than one" error in Django admin

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to access an (unmanaged) model via Django administration dashboard. The model doesn't have a primary key, but instead is unique across three fields.

```
class MyObjectView(models.Model):
    solution_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    scenario_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    object_id = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    description= models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    year_of_creation = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False  # Created from a view. Don't remove.
        db_table = 'myobject_view'
```

While I am able to access the list of all items in the admin dashboard, as soon as I try to view one specific item I get the error:

> get() returned more than one MyObjectView -- it returned 4!

As per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint), I tried adding a `UniqueConstraint` in the `Meta` class, but the constraint doesn't seem to have any effect, and the error above persists:

```
    class Meta:
        managed = False  # Created from a view. Don't remove.
        db_table = 'myobject_view'
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['solution_id', 'scenario_id', 'object_id '], name='unique_object'),
        ]
```

Is this the proper way to solve the `get() returned more than one` error? Should the constraint work even on an unmanaged model?

Comment: what is your admin url, i think there is only one field.

Comment: Django does not support models without pk

Comment: @BearBrown looking into the admin urls, I actually found a couple items that can be displayed. For example, the following url works `http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/admin/my_app/myobjectview/121/change/?_changelist_filters=p%3D10`, while this one raises the `MultipleObjectsReturned` error `http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/admin/my_app/myobjectview/166/change/?_changelist_filters=p%3D9`. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @dirkgroten Thanks, however I was able to access some items in the admin even without specifying any PK (cf. previous comment), so apparently Django at least partially supports such models, no? Anyway, because the view I am modeling is managed by a third party, I probably can't include any PK. Would there exist any workarounds?

Comment: Try looking at the query. 166 represents one of the fields and Django has to pick one. In your console try `MyObjectView.objects.get(pk=166).query`

Comment: @dirkgroten Running that command in a Python shell raised `AttributeError: 'MyObjectView' object has no attribute 'query'`, but running just `MyObjectView.objects.get(pk=166)` raised again the `MultipleObjectsReturned` error. Running `MyObjectView.objects.get(pk=121)` led to the result
`<MyObjectView: SolID - 955 -- ScenID 477>`. Could you please explain how Django uses those PKs, even though `managed = False` and the original view doesn't contain PKs? Is there a way to let these PKs be unique with respect to the specified `UniqueConstraint`?

Comment: sorry, `str(MyObjectView.objects.filter(pk=166).query)` is what you want, that way you can see the `WHERE` clause used by Django to match the `pk=166` query. `query` is a property of a `QuerySet`.

Answer (score 1):

I think if the object is unmanaged adding an UniqueConstraint in the Meta won't insert any constraint in the database.

You need to catch the exception:

```
try:
    the_object = MyObjectView.objects.get(
        object_id=object_id, scenario_id=scenario_id, solution_id=solution_id
    )
    return the_object # or do something different
except MyObjectView.MultipleObjectsReturned:
    # multiple objects have the three same values
    # manage that case
    return None # just as example
```

Take a look to the reference of [MultipleObjectsReturned exception](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/exceptions/#multipleobjectsreturned)

Comment: Thanks, I would like to try this approach, but I'm not sure where to add this exception catching, so that it affects only the django admin, could you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to add .first() to your get().  That guarantees you will get a single result (or None), and will avoid errors at that point.

If the duplicates are a problem it sounds like you need to investigate how they are being created, fix that and then do some clear up.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed seems like a viable temporary fix! However I'm not sure where I should edit the get() command that is used by the Django admin. Is that possible?

Comment: You could try overriding get_queryset in your model admin.  See
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset